# How do I pass id from function into the promise.all in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios

I want to pass id of previous selected value into another select function.
I have 3 select menu that are dependent to each other. Example

user have to select the State first than , district after that they can select the city value.

With this code I got error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined` How to solve this ?

This is what I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#state").change(function() {
    let state = $(this).val();
    getDistrict(state);
  });


  $("#district").change(function() {
    let district = $(this).val();
    getCity(district);
  });

});

function getStateList() {
  return axios.get(`${url}state`);
}

function getDistrict(state) {
  return axios.get(`${url}dist?state_id=${state}`);
}

function getCity(district) {
  return axios.get(`${url}city?district_id=${district}`);
}
```

Comment: `a` is defined?

Comment: Maybe you can do something like `getDistrict.map(callback => callback(a)).then(values => { }), getCity.......`

Comment: @nazarpunk sorry but i dont get it ?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen in the same line as this one `Promise.all([getStateList(), getDistrict(a), getCity(b)])` ?

Comment: In your code no `a` or `b` is defined.

Comment: @mailme yes but that is not working, let me see if i can fix it,.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I don´t know what you are talking about. If he passes `a` as a parameter to `getDistrict`, it has to be defined.

Comment: @StevenSiebert do I have to pass variable `state` is that what you mean in the `getDistrict(state)`

Comment: @mailme I answered this question and described how you could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that `a` and `b` aren´t declared. You can use the var `state` to call `getDistrict`, because you use it in the enviroment of your function.

If you want to access `state` as `a` and `district` as `b`, you need to declare them outside of your functions. This could be something like this:

```
var a;
var b;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#state").change(function() {
    a = $(this).val();
    getDistrict(a);
  });


  $("#district").change(function() {
    b = $(this).val();
    getCity(b);
  });

});

function getStateList() {
  return axios.get(`${url}state`);
}

function getDistrict(state) {
  return axios.get(`${url}dist?state_id=${state}`);
}

function getCity(district) {
  return axios.get(`${url}city?district_id=${district}`);
}


Promise.all([getStateList(), getDistrict(a), getCity(b)])
  .then(function(results) {
//code
});
```